# How can we scrape src link using python Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, automation, screen-scraping

How I can scrape src image link using python beautifulsoup??

```html
<div class="image-view-magnifier-wrap"><img alt="2-Piece hoodie and sweatpants Suit sportswear men and women sweatshirt suit jogging pullovers" class="magnifier-image" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H5db0c681ba2e4ce3a4cf6963548e6c833/2-Piece-hoodie-and-sweatpants-Suit-sportswear-men-and-women-sweatshirt-suit-jogging-pullovers.jpg_Q90.jpg_.webp" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: auto;"><div class="magnifier-loading-wrap" style="display: none;"><div class="magnifier-loading-cover"></div><div class="magnifier-loading"></div></div><div class="magnifier-cover" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.detail.1000017.i0.7fd2579bO2tCaS"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your data as html you can find main_div which has img tag and then extract tag from it by using this method

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
main_div=soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"image-view-magnifier-wrap"})

main_div.find("img")['src']
```

OR

```
img=main_div.find("img")
img.attrs['src']
```

Output:

```
'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H5db0c681ba2e4ce3a4cf6963548e6c833/2-Piece-hoodie-and-sweatpants-Suit-sportswear-men-and-women-sweatshirt-suit-jogging-pullovers.jpg_Q90.jpg_.webp'
```